# Scheduled job doesn't run again

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have spring batch project with code like this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public Job xmlJob() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("XMLjob")
                .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("XML")
                        .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
                        .reader(personXmlReader())
                        .processor(xmlPersonProcessor())
                        .writer(displayData())
                        .build()
                )
                .build();
    }

@Bean
    StaxEventItemReader personXmlReader() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Reader");
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Person.class);
        jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();

        StaxEventItemReader staxEventItemReader = new StaxEventItemReader();
        staxEventItemReader.setName("persons");
        staxEventItemReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("person.xml"));
        staxEventItemReader.setFragmentRootElementName("person");
        staxEventItemReader.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller);

        return staxEventItemReader;
    }

@Override
    public Person process(final Person person) throws Exception {

        final int id = person.getPersonId();
        final String firstName = person.getFirstName().toUpperCase();
        final String lastName = person.getLastName().toUpperCase();
        final int age = person.getAge();
        final String job = person.getJob();

        final Person transformedPerson = new Person(id, firstName, lastName, age+1, job);
        log.info("Job Converting (" + person + ") into (" + transformedPerson + ")");
        return transformedPerson;
    }
```

Program reads structure from xml file and just prints it into console.
Problem is that job doesn't run again and I don't know why.
When I write something like this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public String show(){
        System.out.println("System");
        return null;
    }
```

program is running fine...
I have @EnableScheduling enabled.

Comment: why are you mixing @Bean with @Scheduled?

Comment: This doesn't change nothing during run

Comment: With a fixed rate you are building Jobs without ever executing them. What is Spring supposed to do with this enormous number of built jobs aside from passing each to the garbage collector?

Comment: Without executing them? I dont understand what do you mean...